# Flutter - Webview_plugin - I can't enable full screen with video

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-webview

I use a flutter_webview_plugin to display the web page in the application, but when there is a video on the page there is no option to enable the full screen. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Maybe some other plugin to display the page in the application?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

String url = "https://youtube.com/";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Webview Example',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => Home(),
        "/webview": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("WebView"),
          ),
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          withZoom: true,
        )
      },
    );
  }
}

//Rest of the code

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("WebView"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: controller,
                ),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Open Webview"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/webview");
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: video on page is controlled by the page, so if there's no option, perhaps there's no option at all. Check whether you're seeing a fullscreen button via your mobile browser.

Comment: Of course it works well in the browser - there is a full screen option.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappbrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser) (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)).

An example with a youtube video is presented below:

```dart
...

child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPW7nDBqt8w",
  initialHeaders: {},
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
      )
  ),
  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
    webView = controller;
  },
  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

  },
),

...
```